# How to overwrite css style in a specific page?

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
#amor_di_mundo{
  color:#ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='divL'>
<div id='amor_di_mundo'>Amor di Mundo</div>
<div id='quem_boe'>Quem Boe</div>
</div>
```

index.css

```
#divL div{
color:#800000;
}
```

In `index.css` a div `(#amor_di_mundo)` is styled with `color:800000`

In a specific file I need to overwrite it with `color:#ffffff` but it's not overwritten !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with css specificity: a inline style has more power than an external file. 
Use the same selector, and move the inline styles in a default stylesheet, then add your new styles in a desired file and load first the default stylesheet, then the second stylesheet that you want to overwrite with

Answer (score 1):

The css would need to follow the same rule. So it would need to be

```
#divL div {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

You could mark it as important to get around this:

```
#amor_di_mundo {
    color: #ffffff !important
}
```

Comment: Carl, this is just an example. Should I use `!important` for each element I want to restyle ? I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

As `#divL div` is more specific than `#amor_di_mundo`.

You need to apply  either `color: #ffffff !important` to or write css like this:

```
#divL #amor_di_mundo{
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to put the syle attribute not in header but where the element is in the body itself. The syntax to follow is:

Style="color:#ffffff;"

Add it to the opening tag of the element.